# sending email in python 3.3 Issue

Tags: email, python-3.x, smtp

I am trying to send an email in python 3.3. 
Error sending message is returned.
No syntax errors are returned.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!!!

```
import smtplib
TO = 'someGreatPerson@gmail.com'
SUBJECT = 'Test Email'
TEXT = 'Test Email From Py Script'

gmail_sender = 'sender@gmail.com'
gmail_passwd = 'sender'sPassword'
server = smtplib.SMTP( 'smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.ehlo()
server.login('gmail_sender', 'gmail_passwd')

BODY = '\r\n'.join([
        'To: %s' % 'TO',
        'From: %s' % 'gmail_sender',
        'Subject: %s' % 'SUBJECT',
        '',
        'TEXT'
        ])

try:
    server.sendmail (gmail_sender [TO], BODY)
    print ("email sent")
except:
    print ("error sending email")
server.quit()
```

Comment: There's a `'` in gmail_passwd, you have to escape that!

Comment: Pull out the `try:` and `except:` and let the thrown exception produce some output. Then add that to your question.

Comment: As, Jason suggests, most important is to stop stifling the exception--either remove the try/catch block, or change it to `except e: print(e)`. Also, worth noting that you're missing a comma in `server.sendmail` which should have 3 arguments (in addition to `self`), so there should be a comma between `gmail_sender` and `[TO]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allow exceptions to propagate, to see the full traceback. And enable debug output, to see the exchange with the smtp server:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.header    import Header

smtp_host = 'smtp.gmail.com'
login, password = 'sender@gmail.com', "sender'sPassword"
to_emails = ['someGreatPerson@gmail.com']

msg = MIMEText('Test Email From Py Script…', 'plain', 'utf-8')
msg['Subject'] = Header('Test Email…', 'utf-8')
msg['From'] = login
msg['To'] = ", ".join(to_emails)


s = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_host, 587, timeout=10)
s.set_debuglevel(1) # enable debug output
try:
    s.starttls()
    s.login(login, password)
    s.send_message(msg)
finally:
    s.quit()
```

Note: [`starttls()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.starttls),  [`login()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.login), and [`sendmail()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.sendmail) send `EHLO` themselves if necessary.